# Which is the best way to set/drop boolean flag inside lambda function

Tags: java, lambda

Say I have a currency rates loader returning `isLoaded=true` result only when all the rates are loaded successfully:

```
//List<String> listFrom = Stream.of("EUR", "RUB").collect(toList());
//List<String> listTo = Stream.of("EUR", "CNY").collect(toList());

boolean isLoaded = true;

final FixerDataProvider httpProvider = new FixerDataProvider(maxAttempts);
final List<CurrencyRatePair> data =
    listFrom.stream()
        .flatMap(from -> {
            final List<CurrencyRatePair> result = httpProvider.findRatesBetweenCurrencies(from, listTo);
            if (Objects.isNull(result) || result.size() == 0) {
                isLoaded = false; //!!!Not working as ineffectively final!!!
            }
            return result.stream();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

if (!isLoaded) {
    return false;
}

// do smth with loaded data 

return true;
```

Assignment `isLoaded = false;` inside lambda function is not allowed when `isLoaded` variable is not final or effectively final.

**Which is the most elegant solution to set/drop boolean flag inside lambda expressions?**

**What do you think about AtomicBoolean and set(false) method as a possible approach?**

Comment: You could use an `AtomicBoolean`, but instead I'd just use an old-style loop. Lambdas should not have side-effects at all.

Comment: Or just try to access the `stream` and handle the occurring `NullPointerException`, but this will not return `false` for empty lists.

Comment: There seem to be other logical problems with your stream, since you are not using 'from' in your lambda, just the fromList... If you fix that part, perhaps you can compare if the resulting list length is the expected length? You are not returning the resulting list either...

Comment: @per-huss Thx, fixed in snippet. Good idea about length comparing! But the question is more about methodology )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may be better off with an old-style loop, as others have suggested. It does feel like a bit of a programming faux pas to write lambdas with side-effects, but you're likely to find an equal number of developers who think it's fine too.

As for getting this particular lambda-with-side effects working, making `isLoaded` into an `AtomicBoolean` is probably your best bet. You could achieve the same effect by making `isLoaded` a `boolean[]` of size 1, but that seems less elegant than going with `AtomicBoolean` to me.

But seriously, try using an old-school loop instead too and see which one you like better.

---

If you use [parallel stream](https://www.baeldung.com/java-when-to-use-parallel-stream#2-parallel-streams), you must use `AtomicBoolean`. Because `boolean[1]` may not be thread safe in `parallel` scenario.

Comment: I think a lot of programmers find that there is a certain elegance and convenience to using the Stream API and lambdas, and prefer to use them over 'old' loops, but eventually they run into this issue with side effects, so there's a bit of a clash.

Comment: Actually, I think side effects is not a definitely evil. As I do not plan to have a pure function, why not to take an advantages of the functional coding style (compactness and readability)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm on the fence when it comes to the relative wickedness of side effects in Java lambdas. The rule of thumb I generally use in Java is, if a lambda with side effects reduces the amount of code written AND the scope of the side effects are limited to a single method body, then it really isn't going to hurt anything. At least I haven't heard an argument against doing thing this way that didn't seem pedantic. Seems like if you're truly worried about side effects at that level, then functional Java probably isn't functional enough for you in the first place :)

Comment: what is the `boolean[]` of size 1 solution? I'm curious

Comment: You can use `Boolean[] isLoaded = new Boolean[1];` and modify `isLoaded[0]` inside lambda.

Answer (score 3):

The [java.util.stream javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) states that

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.

That said, if you want to do it anyway, the solution you have identified with an AtomicBoolean will do the trick just fine.

Comment: I just wanted to update my post with additional question... Why it is forbidden to use non-effectively final variables while there're several ways to bypass this rule? But I guess you just brought me to the right answer. Is it made so to minimize possible side effects?

Comment: Oh, the non-effectively final variable thing has to do with that lambdas are really inner classes under the hood, and an inner class may not refer to a local non-final variable. Before Java 8 you had to explicitly declare such a variable with `final`, but nowadays it's enough that you treat it as a final by not changing its value, i.e. effectively final... If you use an AtomicBoolean you're not reassigning the variable, but modifying the state of the object it refers to instead, and thus treating it effectively final. Do I make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Variables used within anonymous inner classes and lambda expression have to be effectively final.

You can use AtomicReference for your case, here is a similar snippet from [ConditionEvaluationListenerJava8Test](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=awaitility-master/awaitility-java8-test/src/test/java/com/jayway/awaitility/ConditionEvaluationListenerJava8Test.java)

```
public void expectedMatchMessageForAssertionConditionsWhenUsingLambdasWithoutAlias() { 
    final AtomicReference<String> lastMatchMessage = new AtomicReference<>(); 
    CountDown countDown = new CountDown(10); 
    with() 
            .conditionEvaluationListener(condition -> { 
                try { 
                    countDown.call(); 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
                } 
                lastMatchMessage.set(condition.getDescription()); 
            }) 
            .until(() -> assertEquals(5, (int) countDown.get())); 

    String expectedMatchMessage = String.format("%s reached its end value", CountDown.class.getName()); 
    assertThat(lastMatchMessage.get(), allOf(startsWith("Condition defined as a lambda expression"), endsWith(expectedMatchMessage))); 
}
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand you will get `isLoaded=false` only in case if all off `result` lists will be empty (If `result` list is null you will get NPE in the next line so there is no any reason to do null check in this way). In this case your `data` list also will be empty and you don't need any boolean flags, just check if `data.isEmpty()` and return false if `true`.

Comment: No, I'm expecting `isLoaded=false` when any of results is null or empty.

Comment: Than it means that it is bad solution to use stream in current case, there is no possibility to interapt stream by some condition, you should use loop in your case.

Comment: Maybe it is not so bad if I want for ex. to log all the failed attempts during the loop without it's termination. And only when the loop is totally completed, than 'll make a final decision.